# TestFirst.org Learn_ruby rake and depreciation warnings :should and :expect syntax

Tags: ruby, linux, rspec, test-first, deprecation-warning

After many searches via Google I'm ready to get some input from the community.  I'm trying to apply for App Academy in San Francisco and one of the required pre-work is TestFirst's Learn_ruby. I original had this configured on a Linux VM on my windows box. It worked very well. When I ran rake it would list one problem at a time; the text was is helpful colors; and the output was very condensed so I only got what I needed to read.  I've recently wiped and configured my system as a dual boot Xubuntu 14.04/ Windows and the VM I once had is long gone.  I worked to get Ruby setup in my linux vm just as I had done in the VM.

My problem now is when I run `rake` on my projects I get the same depreciation warning:

> Deprecation Warnings:
>
> Using `should` from rspec-expectations' old `:should` syntax without
>   explicitly enabling the syntax is deprecated. Use the new `:expect`
>   syntax or explicitly enable `:should` instead. Called from
>   /home/kaji/Projects/learn_ruby/05_silly_blocks/silly_blocks_spec.rb:25:in
>   `block (3 levels) in '.

After googling this back and forth I understand for the most part what the error is telling me. And I've even found a solution to get it to go away. Thanks to this post: [RSpec's New Expectation Syntax](http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2012/06/rspecs-new-expectation-syntax), I was able to find a syntax to make the warning go away. (basicly had to change `blah.should == #` to `expect(blah()).to eq(#)` inside the `*_spec.rb` file.  This seems to make the warning happy. However I still see signs that I have another problem.

The output isn't as 'friendly' as it was when I was on my VM. It's not in color; it dumps all the errors at once. What I enjoyed the most about learn_ruby was it gave me one objective at a time with minimal output.  Now i have to scroll up quite a ways just to see what my issues are.

I've tired removing RVM completely and all gems and reinstalling to see if I could resolve this. No dice.  I'm such a Ruby Noobie i'm a little overwhelmed with all this. I'd like to just get back to learning the basics but this has been troubling me for over a week. Has anyone had this problem/fix the except

I've also tried removing the `rpsec ~<=2.0` from the Rakefile. I'm using `ruby -v 2.1.2`, rails 4.1.1 and i have RSpec 3.0.0, 2.99.0, 2.0.0.  I even tried finding a tutorial on changing the syntax but it was real confusing as it introduced lots of Ruby concepts I have no idea on.  At that point I feel like I'm over my head and there is something simple I'm missing.

Hope I provided enough info for assistance.

Comment: To refine my question. I'm supposed to be learning elementary Ruby topics and I feel i'm wasting productive time troubleshooting a problem which I wonder maybe caused by something else more serious. Thx to Amadan's post Im only having issues with the Warning because I discovered corrupt rakefiles & rspec_config. Can I just ignore the Deprecation Warnings and complete the whole tutorial with out missing anything? Is there a way to turn these warnings off? Is that a bad idea?

Answer (score 2):

I hope I'm answering the correct question, since you seem to have figured out the one in the title (i.e. the preferred syntax having changed from `blah.should` to `expect(blah).to`). It would help if you changed the title to reflect the actual question.

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.fail_fast = true
  config.color_enabled = true
}
```

will make RSpec fail at first error, rather than after running all tests, and enable the colours, for that one file.

Or you can run rspec with `rspec --fail-fast --color`.

Alternately, you can put this in `$HOME/.rspec` so it always does it:

```
--fail-fast
--color
```

Comment: Thanks. That pointed me in the right direction to discover I had corrupt rakefile & rspec_config.rb. Clarifying my question in a comment to my OP